# Codeigniter How to handle MultiSelect data in Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I have a form with the following Multi-Select code:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 45px;">
                        <label class="control-label" for="non-compatibility"><?php echo _l('invoice_suboption_noncompatible'); ?></label>
                        <select multiple class="selectpicker display-block" data-width="100%" name="non-compatibility[]" id="non-compatibility" title='<?php echo _l('invoice_suboption_noncompatible'); ?>'>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php foreach($suboptions as $suboption){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $suboption['name']; ?>" data-subtext="<?php echo $suboption['plat_option']; ?>"><?php echo $suboption['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

In my Model I would like to take the selected values and join them into a single string separated by pipes '|' and then insert that string along with the rest of the form data into my database. I am not sure exactly how to go about doing this. How do I go about looping through 'non-compatibility[]' so I can doing the values. The form data comes in as $data into my Model.

**EDIT:**

My controller takes the post and saves it to $data then calls the model to insert $data into my database.

```
$data = $this->input->post();
$this->invoice_items_model->add($data);
```

Comment: `implode('|', $_POST['non-compatibility'])`

Comment: @u_mulder Since I will be sending the the $data that comes into the model from the form how would I be able to loop through the $data['non-compatibility[]'] fields in order to unset them?

Comment: @u_mulder Using what you said in my controller then unsetting non-compatibility before sending the data to my Model I was able to get it to work. If you post an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @TylerFontaine if you want comma separate value then can use this $non_compatibility=implode(",",$data['non-compatibility']); on model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using what u_mudler was saying if anyone was curious. In the controller I did the following:

```
$data['non_compatible'] = implode('|', $_POST['non-compatibility']);
unset($data['non-compatibility']);
```

This takes the individual 'non-compatibility' fields that were passed by the form and joins them into a single field separated by pipes. The original 'non-compatibility' field in $data was then unset then $data was sent over to the Model. to be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect data will come in implode format only, if you want to loop through each of the selected data, explode it and save it in a variable. Then use the foreach loop to go through each data.

For Example, consider I receive all the multiple selected data in a variable $data, then I would

```
$partThis = explode(",",$data);
foreach($partThis as $value)
{
    if($value==true)
    {
       //execute your code
    }
}
```

You can also explode $data in the model to understand how the data is received.

Comment: I checked my form submission and noticed that the multi-select didn't seem to send a comma separated value. Instead it send multiple fields named 'non-compatibility[]' with each having a value that was selected. Are you saying that when the controller sends that post over to the model it received it as a comma separated field? Also, I'm not exactly sure how to view data from a model to be honest. I'm fairly new to this type of framework.

Comment: That's even better. Directly use foreach loop on $non-compatibility